How to deal with legacy clients (hardcoded IP) after server migration
I am currently preparing the migration of a mysql server to another infrastructure with a new IP. After migration the old server will be shut down. Everything seems to work so far with the new server. One remaining problem is a legacy application where the server IP has been hardcoded. The application is running locally on a few Windows machines. Although I have access to the source code, fixing the application is not an option given the tight schedule.
I need hints for a solution to temporarily redirect traffic between the application and <OLD_SERVER_IP> to <NEW_SERVER_IP>. Preferably it should work directly on the client machines, maybe with an additional tool that needs to be running before starting the application.
As I do not directly manage the server infrastructure, network, or firewalls things may get a lot more complicated when the fix has to be implemented on the server side.
After searching here I already tried netsh portproxy ... and a simple local proxy (https://github.com/cars10/simprox) but could not get it working. The proposed solutions seem to be implemented on a server and I have to admit, that I am still struggling to figure out which of the IPs <OLD_SERVER_IP>, <NEW_SERVER_IP>, <WINDOWSMACHINE_IP>, <LOOPBACK_IP> goes where.
So before evaluating server based solutions my questions are:

is it possible to fix the problem directly on the client machines?
which tools can be used in which way to solve the problem on the client machines?

Thanks in advance.

is it possible to fix the problem directly on the client machines? Yes! Fix the server in the source code and use a DNS name this time.

Thanks for the suggestion. I would, but as I wrote, it is not an option at the moment. I didn't write the application, it is poorly documented and the build infrastructure is outdated and broken. So I need another solution to buy some time. Fixing the application is next on my list.

Just a short update from my side: In the end the easiest solution for us was to split the database and set up another virtual server running under <OLD_SERVER_IP> with the data for the legacy clients. Thanks again for all the answers and comments.

This is not going to be the last time IP addresses change. Do a proper migration and stop using the old IP address, and start using names.

A generic yet detailed procedure:
Start logging traffic to the old IP address with a server firewall and maybe packet capture.
Consider if the new service should go behind a load balancer, proxy, or similar. For application or HA reasons. Maybe not, but if so now is the time to change it.
Add new service IP to DNS to start using names.
Change a test client to the name.
Make it possible to be overridden in some manner of configuration. Config overrides also will make it possible to run an otherwise identical client against a test server, very useful.
Stop the service on the old one, and start it on the new one. Probably more steps in between, like catching up any new database to the desired point in time.
Configure all clients to use the name.  Document what and how to set it wherever people find technical documentation about the thing.
Review firewall logs and find stray clients missed. An optional courtesy to users. Also for your peace of mind that nobody is using it.
Some time later, remove the old IP address.

Thanks for your answer. This is basically what I am doing right now with all other services and applications running on the old server. Most programmers did a good job using names and config files and the migration did run smoothly. The few "stray clients" as you call them are the problematic cases my question was refering to.

This is very good advices and should always be taken in account to conduct painless migrations! However, i believe that this would not really help in this current situation, as @MarcFischer claims that 1) He do not manage his company IT infrastructure (so hard to setup a firewall, loadbalancers, etc..). 2) The running apps have the IP addresses hardcoded (and probably not possible to change this easily).

I think that what you need would be a DNAT firewall rule (on your client machines), for the client network stack changing the Destination IP addresse of packets going outside the system.
The command netsh portproxy alone will not work, because it is more related to 'port forwarding' than 'DNAT', and the clients actually don't own the OLD_IP_Address.
Your situation:
You have a Windows client, having an app running which is trying to connect to a server on an <OLD_SERVER_IP> which doesnt exist anymore, and traffic shall be redirected to a new <NEW_SERVER_IP>. Also worth noting that your app is trying to reach the server on <SERVER_PORT>.
My proposal

Add the <OLD_IP_ADDRESS> to your network interface of your windows client. Example procedure https://aptaredocs.veritas.com/10.3.00/index.html#page/System%2520Administrator's%2520Guide%2F%24H_113.html%23 , but you may probably find the powershell equivalent.
Configure port forwarding on your windows client netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=<OLD_IP_ADDRESS> listenport=<SERVER_PORT> connectaddress=<NEW_IP_ADDRESS> connectport=<SERVER_PORT>
The automatic routing configuration should do the rest of the job

Finally, your client app shall be able to connect to the server on its new IP address.
N.b: this configuration may not be persistent accross reboots, please consider adding it to your startup config.

Thanks for your proposal. I assume I can only do that after the old server is not running under <OLD_IP_ADDRESS> anymore because of potential address conflict? I can try it in a few days, when the migration of all other processes is finished.

Yes probably (it also depends on the IT infrastructure, routing and IP addresses ranges and masks) . You may also consider to add a "windows firewall defender" stateful rule denyiing any "New" exterior requests (except your app: 127.0.0.1 and your WAN ip address), as to drop any traffic that would request this <OLD_SERVER_IP> at you Windows client side.
